# Exist some kind of Ordering object in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pagedlist

I developing a paged service to retrieve data from database using NHibernate.
In my actual point I'm receiving a skip, take and **string** order parameter.

My question is, exist some native library to ordering in .NET, something that consider asc or desc ordering, maybe the list of field to order in priority.

e.g: Order Name Asc, City Desc.

So:
Paul | New York
Paul | Amsterdam

--
**Edit**

```
IEnumerable<Obj> actuals = _repository.LoadByName("Pa", p => p.Name);
```

And the method signature:

```
public IEnumerable<Obj> LoadByName<TKey> (string name, Func<Obj, TKey> ordering = null, int skip = 0, int take = 0) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ --> [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), [ThenByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx)

Comment: Nice, but how can I create my method signature? Something like `IEnumerable<Obj> ListByName(string name, Func<Obj, TKEY> ordering, int skip = 0, int take = 0)`

Comment: @Custódio you'll only be able to sort on one field that way, it depends on you criteria for sorting

Comment: I'll put in my question the actual the actual solution. The problem is I can't say the ordering (asc,desc)

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` has a [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) Method.

Comment: If you were going to do it this way (which I am not advocating), you would use `SortedList`.